# In HTML5, can my <!DOCTYPE html> declaration contain anything else?

Tags: html, doctype

I'm trying to specify my  declaration at the beggining of my .html file. Now, in HTML 4.01 or XHTML 1.1, W3C has a few extra things, such as this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Does HTML5 contain any such thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ## [8.1.1 The DOCTYPE](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-doctype)
>
> A **DOCTYPE** is a required preamble.
>
> > **Note**: DOCTYPEs are required for legacy reasons. When omitted, browsers tend to use a different rendering mode that is incompatible
> >     with some specifications. Including the DOCTYPE in a document ensures
> >     that the browser makes a best-effort attempt at following the relevant
> >     specifications.
>
> A DOCTYPE must consist of the following components, in this order:
>
> 1. A string that is an [ASCII case-insensitive](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#ascii-case-insensitive) match for the string "<!DOCTYPE".
> 2. One or more [space characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#space-character).
> 3. A string that is an [ASCII case-insensitive](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#ascii-case-insensitive) match for the string "html".
> 4. Optionally, a [DOCTYPE legacy string](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#doctype-legacy-string) or an [obsolete permitted DOCTYPE string](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#obsolete-permitted-doctype-string) (defined below).
> 5. Zero or more [space characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#space-character).
> 6. A ">" (U+003E) character.
>
> > **Note**: In other words, `<!DOCTYPE html>`, case-insensitively.
>
> For the purposes of HTML generators that cannot output HTML markup
>   with the short DOCTYPE "`<!DOCTYPE html>`", a **DOCTYPE legacy
>   string** may be inserted into the DOCTYPE (in the position defined
>   above). This string must consist of:
>
> 1. One or more [space characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#space-character).
> 2. A string that is an [ASCII case-insensitive](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#ascii-case-insensitive) match for the string "`SYSTEM`".
> 3. One or more [space characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#space-character).
> 4. A U+0022 QUOTATION MARK or U+0027 APOSTROPHE character (*the quote mark*).
> 5. The literal string "[`about:legacy-compat`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#about:legacy-compat)".
> 6. A matching U+0022 QUOTATION MARK or U+0027 APOSTROPHE character (i.e. the same character as in the earlier step labeled *quote mark*).
>
> > **Note**: In other words, `<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">` or `<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM 'about:legacy-compat'>`,
> >     case-insensitively except for the part in single or double quotes.
>
> The [DOCTYPE legacy string](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#doctype-legacy-string) should not be used unless the document
>   is generated from a system that cannot output the shorter string.
>
> To help authors transition from HTML4 and XHTML1, an o**bsolete
>   permitted DOCTYPE string** can be inserted into the DOCTYPE (in the
>   position defined above). This string must consist of:
>
> 1. One or more [space characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#space-character).
> 2. A string that is an [ASCII case-insensitive](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#ascii-case-insensitive) match for the string "`PUBLIC`".
> 3. One or more [space characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#space-character).
> 4. A U+0022 QUOTATION MARK or U+0027 APOSTROPHE character (the *first quote mark*).
> 5. The string from one of the cells in the first column of the table below. The row to which this cell belongs is the *selected row*.
> 6. A matching U+0022 QUOTATION MARK or U+0027 APOSTROPHE character (i.e. the same character as in the earlier step labeled *first quote
>      mark*).
> 7. If a system identifier is used,
>
>    1. One or more [space characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#space-character).
>    2. A U+0022 QUOTATION MARK or U+0027 APOSTROPHE character (the *third quote mark*).
>    3. The string from the cell in the second column of the *selected row*.
>    4. A matching U+0022 QUOTATION MARK or U+0027 APOSTROPHE character (i.e. the same character as in the earlier step labeled *third quote
>         mark*).
>
> Allowed values for public and system identifiers in an [obsolete
>   permitted DOCTYPE string](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#obsolete-permitted-doctype-string).
>
> ```
> ┌────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────┐
> │Public identifier               │System identifier                                │System identifier optional?│
> ├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┤ 
> │-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN        │http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd       │Yes                        │
> │-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN       │http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd            │Yes                        │
> │-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN│http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd│No                         │
> │-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN       │http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd     │No                         │
> └────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────┘
> ```
>
> A [DOCTYPE](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-doctype) containing an [obsolete permitted DOCTYPE string](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#obsolete-permitted-doctype-string) is
>   an **obsolete permitted DOCTYPE**. Authors should not use [obsolete
>   permitted DOCTYPEs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#obsolete-permitted-doctype), as they are unnecessarily long.

Comment: Update: obsolete HTML 4.0 doctypes have now been declared non-conforming (though the page will still render in no-quirk mode). See https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/2048 .

Answer (score 6):

In HTML5,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

is *one of* the allowed doctype declarations. And it is the *recommended one*. 
Note that it's case INsensitive in HTML5.

Still, if you are absolutely forced to use something similar to HTML4/XHTML, you may use the *legacy-compatible doctype*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
```

This may be the case if you use some software or framework to *generate* your HTML5 documents.

If you are just authoring new HTML5 documents, you are encouraged to just use `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

More reading:

- [WHATWG HTML5 living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-doctype)
- [W3C HTML5 Reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#doctype-declaration) (might be outdated)

Comment: Please see my answer. He's actually looking to use an "obsolete permitted DOCTYPE".

Comment: Yeah, thanks, edited to make it even more clear that the legacy stuff should be avoided if possible.

Comment: It's best not to reference http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author . That's a five years out-of-date draft document. There have been many changes to HTML5 since that was written, although admittedly the DOCTYPE stuff is still the same.

Comment: @Alohci, thanks for the valuable advice; included link to WHATWG specs on doctype.

Answer (score 1):

Those are allowed but make it an "obsolete permitted DOCTYPE". The specifications state `"Authors should not use obsolete permitted DOCTYPEs"`

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#the-doctype

These are only included to help developers transition from HTML4 and XHTML1 to HTML5 but should be considered `deprecated` and you should avoid them if possible.

Another warning: in older browsers, you might not get the right document rendering mode if you don't use the simple `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

HTML 4.01 was based on Standard Generalized Markup Language (SGML). In order for a browser to ba able to render the page correctly the DTD had to be specified.

HTML 5 is not based on SGML. Therefore it does not need a reference to the DTD. So its just:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

for HTML5